# find the simple closed curve of $F(x,y) = (y^3-6y)i + (6x-x^3)j$ using Green's Theorem which will have the largest positive value

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

**$F(x,y) = (y^3-6y)i + (6x-x^3)j$**

**a. Using Green's Theorem, find the simple closed curve C for which the integral 
$ ∳F \cdot dr  $ (with positive orientation) will have the largest positive value.**

**b. Compute this largest possible value.**

I'm quite certain that this is just $ \iint Nx-My $ $dA$ but I do not know how to find the bounds in this scenario for both integrals. Though I'm also sure that this problem can also be done using just $ ∳ F \cdot dr $ as there is an equation given for F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that if we integrate around a closed curve $C$ that bounds a region $\Omega$, then 
$$
\oint F \cdot dr = \iint_{\Omega} (N_x - M_y) dA.
$$
Here, we have 
$$
(N_x - M_y)(x,y) = (6 - 3x^2) + (6-3y^2) = 12 - 3(x^2 + y^2). \tag{1}
$$  In order to maximize $\iint_{\Omega} (N_x - M_y) dA$, we want $\Omega$ to include all the points where $ N_x - M_y$ is positive and none of the points where it is negative.  From (1) it is apparent that  $(N_x - M_y)(x,y) \geq 0$ if and only if $x^2 + y^2 \leq 4$, i.e. $(N_x - M_y)(x,y) \geq 0$ if and only if $(x,y)$ is in a disk of radius $2$ centered at the origin.

Comment: So that would mean that the bounds would be from 0 to 2 for both integrals, correct?

Comment: No, if you wanted to do it in Cartesian coordinates, the bounds would be from $-2$ to $2$ for $x$ and $ \pm \sqrt{4-x^2}$ for $y$ (or the same but with the roles of $x$ and $y$ reversed).  I would *not* use Cartesian coordinates for part b though.  It is much better suited for polar coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I suspected as much, so θ would be from 0 to 4π, and then r would be 0 to 2? Or would it be from -4π to 4π and -2 to 2 for θ and r respectively?

Comment: You’re right that $r$ should go from $0$ to $2$, but the limits for theta should be taken to be $0$ and $2 \pi$ (or, alternatively, any real numbers with a difference of $2 \pi$).

Comment: Ok, I thought that because the disk was radius 2, that theta should be from 0 to 4π, but that makes sense because it's only one rotation around the unit disk with radius 2. Thank you so much for the help!